# Non existent files not getting redirected to my custom 404 page. Works fine in local server

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

The below is my `.htaccess` file placed in the root

> ErrorDocument 404 http://www.abc.com/404.php Redirect
>   /services/something.php http://www.abc.com/index.php

The second line is irrelevant I guess.

The problem is that it redirects any non existent file to my 404.php perfectly when I run it in my local WAMP server. But with the same is not happening when I upload it to my server. What could be wrong?

Also, if I write

`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` instead of `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.abc.com/404.php` it won't even work in the localhost.

I get the error message saying

> The requested URL /abc/xxxx was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>   Why does this error occur when every website I refer has recommended `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Comment: is it readable? what are the permissions on the file once uploaded the the server? (you may need to chmod it to 644)

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php` worked for me

Comment: The permission already is 644 :(

Comment: Also I dont think changing the name from /404.php to /error.php will make any difference. or will it?

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure that the 404.php is present in the proper location and http://www.abc.com/404.php is working properly.

if both 404.php and .htaccess are present in the same **root** folder, then
try changing following line in .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

to

```
ErrorDocument 404 /root/404.php
```

Comment: By **root** folder I mean the top level folder.
Also the 404.php is working fine and is present at http://www.abc.com/404.php i.e root